# jqGrid multi level grouping behaving oddly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've run into a bit of an odd case, and I wonder if someone might be able to help.

In the code I am working with, I have been using multiple level (2) grouping for several months now, and without any problems.  I recently had a request to add a third level of grouping, which caused the furling (+/- toggling) on that level to behave oddly.

The three levels, by groupField name are, respectively: part_description, locn_abbr, and corporation_abbr.  corporation_abbr is the recent third level addition.  Example output looks like this:

1.1 Part Description 1

1.2 Location

1.3 Customer 1

2.1 Part Description 2

2.2 Location 2

2.3 Customer 2

3.1 Part Description 3

3.2 Location 3

3.3 Customer 3

Clicking + next to Part Description or Location will, as expected, expand the data below Customer.  Clicking – next to either also works properly, with the data rolling back up to the appropriate level.

Clicking + next to Customer expands the data as expected.  Clicking – rolls up the current entry's customer data as well as the next entry's customer data, which also removes the next entry's Part Description and Location levels.  Using the above example, assuming I've clicked – next to the first entry's customer level, it would look like this:

1.1 Part Description 1

1.2 Location 1

1.3 Customer 1

1.3 Customer 2

3.1 Part Description 3

3.2 Location 3

3.3 Customer 3

Additionally, if I click + next to 1.3 Customer 2, that entire entry is redrawn as it was before, below entry 1.

I've googled this problem with every conceivable search term, but haven't found anything.  When that didn't work, I looked at the source, and messed around with groupingToggle a bit.  I didn't have any success with that, either.  Does anyone have any insight into this problem?  Is there something obvious I'm missing in the code snippet I provided?

This is a snippet of the grouping code:

```
grouping: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ['part_description', 'locn_abbr', 'corporation_abbr'],
            groupOrder: ['desc', 'asc', 'desc'],
            groupColumnShow: [false, false, false],
            groupText: ['<span style="font-weight: bold; background: #D8D8D8; padding: 3px; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-top: 2px; border: 1px solid #A4A4A4; width: 650px; display: inline-block;">{0}</span>', '<span style="font-weight: bold; width: 200px; display: inline-block;">Location: {0}</span><span style=" width: 200px; font-weight: bold; display: inline-block;">Weight: {current_item_weight}</span>', '<span style="width: 200px; display: inline-block;">Customer: {0}</span><span>Weight: {current_item_weight}</span>'],
            groupCollapse: true,
            groupSummary: [false, false, false],
            groupDataSorted: true
        },
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having similar problems today - I think there might be a bug in there for levels > 2. I will post back if I find a solution.

Comment: Hey there.  Any word on this?  (It's at least comforting to know I wasn't just crazy, and someone else was seeing this, too.)

Comment: Hey swos, I believe in my situation I ended up going with a "grid as subgrid" solution. Check v4.4.3, I believe there were some modifications to grouping that may fix your issue. Also, I had hacked up a version to get 3 level grouping to work the way I wanted it to (choosing to expand/collapse by level) - let me know if that's something you would want and I'll send it to you.

Comment: Thanks for responding again. I would definitely appreciate a look at what you've worked out for a solution. This was actually an issue on a project working for a previous employer, though I would like to forward along any possible solution to a former coworker there who inherited the issue. (I'll mention 4.4.3 as well.)

Comment: Hey @swos, sorry it took so long to get back to you. If you still need it, I posted my tweaks to jqGrid on my GitHub repo. I posted some info on their forums, [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/grouping-with-collapsed-groups-bug/#p28574). Take care.

Comment: Hey @IronicMuffin thanks for the feedback and no worries!  I appreciate the help.  It was maddening thinking I was the only one experiencing this issue.